# Save data in form after wrong submit (JSP/Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

How to prevent the jsp form from resetting? I have a jsp form that passes data to a servlet. If the user presses "submit" without having filled in all the fields, an error message is displayed inviting the user to fill in all the fields of the form. The problem is that when the error message appears, the data entered by the user in the form is cleared. How can I make sure that this data is saved and that the user doesn't have to rewrite everything again?

I mean that it must be a method that allows me to keep the form filled in, because it must work even if, for example, all the fields are filled in and the email field does not have the @ symbol.

This is my jsp:

## Aggiungi un nuovo contatto

```
<form method="POST"  action="AggiungiPersona.do">


    Id: <input type="number" size="40 maxlength=40" name="id" required /><br />
    Nome: <input type="text" size="40 maxlength=40" name="nome" required /><br />
    Cognome: <input type="text" size="40 maxlength=40" name="cognome" required /><br />
    Anni: <input type="number" size="40 maxlength=40" name="anni" required /><br />
    Sesso: <input type="text" size="40 maxlength=40" name="sesso" required /><br />
    Indirizzo: <input type="text" size="40 maxlength=40" name="indirizzo" required /><br />
    Numero di telefono: <input type="text" size="40 maxlength=40"
        name="numTel" required /><br /> 
    Email: <input type="text"
        size="40 maxlength=40" name="email" required /><br /> 
    <br> <input type="submit" value="crea contatto">

 </form>



<c:choose>


    <c:when test="${error==true}">
        <h3>Errore</h3>
        <p>Attenzione! Inserire un'età compresa tra 0 e 100.</p>
        <br> <br> <a href="./index.jsp">Torna alla HomePage</a> 
    </c:when>

    <c:when test="${error2==true}">
        <h3>Errore</h3>
        <p>Attenzione! L'id che si sta cercando di inserire è già
            presente in database. Scegliere un id diverso.</p>
            <br> <br> <a href="./index.jsp">Torna alla HomePage</a> 
    </c:when>

    <c:when test="${error3==true}">
        <h3>Errore</h3>
        <p>Attenzione! Il valore associato a "sesso" può essere solo "m",
            "M", "f", "F".</p>
            <br> <br> <a href="./index.jsp">Torna alla HomePage</a> 
    </c:when>

    <c:when test="${error4==true}">
        <h3>Errore</h3>
        <p>Attenzione! Il numero di telefono può contenere solo numeri.</p>
        <br> <br> <a href="./index.jsp">Torna alla HomePage</a> 
    </c:when>

    <c:when test="${error5==true}">
        <h3>Errore</h3>
        <p>Attenzione! L'email deve contenre il simbolo '@'.</p>
        <br> <br> <a href="./index.jsp">Torna alla HomePage</a> 
    </c:when>
    
    <c:when test="${error6==true}">
        <h3>Errore</h3>
        <p>Attenzione! Tutti i campi del form devono essere compilati.</p>
        <br> <br> <a href="./index.jsp">Torna alla HomePage</a> 
    </c:when>

    <c:when test="${successo==true}">
        <h3>Aggiunto nuovo contatto!</h3>

        <p>
            Id:
            <% String id = request.getParameter("id"); out.print(id); %>
            <br /> Nome:
            <% String nome = request.getParameter("nome"); out.print(nome); %>
            <br /> Cognome:
            <% String cognome = request.getParameter("cognome"); out.print(cognome); %>
            <br /> Età:
            <% String anni = request.getParameter("anni"); out.print(anni); %>
            <br /> Sesso:
            <% String sesso = request.getParameter("sesso"); out.print(sesso); %>
            <br /> Indirizzo:
            <% String indirizzo = request.getParameter("indirizzo"); out.print(indirizzo); %>
            <br /> Numero di telefono:
            <% String numTel = request.getParameter("numTel"); out.print(numTel); %>
            <br /> Email:
            <% String email= request.getParameter("email"); out.print(email); %>

            <br> <br> <a href="./index.jsp">Torna alla HomePage</a> 
        </p>
        

    </c:when>

</c:choose>
```

this is my servlet:

```
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public AggiungiPersona() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    
    
    // verifica se esiste una sessione già creata
            // se no: reindirizzo l'utente in login.html
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            
            if(session == null || session.getAttribute("loggedIn")==null || !session.getAttribute("loggedIn").equals(true)) {
               response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
               
                return;
            }
            
            

    // prendo tutte le persone dal db e le metto in arrayList per poterci ciclare
    // sopra e controllare se l'id inserito esiste gia nella collezione

    ArrayList<Persona> listaPersone = null;
    listaPersone = PersonaQuery.getPersone();

    boolean found = false;

    if (request.getParameter("id") == "" || request.getParameter("nome") == ""
            || request.getParameter("cognome") == "" || request.getParameter("anni") == ""
            || request.getParameter("sesso") == "" || request.getParameter("indirizzo") == ""
            || request.getParameter("numTel") == "" || request.getParameter("email") == ""

    ) {
        request.setAttribute("error6", true);

        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("aggiungiPersona.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);

    } else if ((Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("anni")) < 0)
            || (Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("anni")) > 100)) {
        request.setAttribute("error", true);

        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("aggiungiPersona.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);

    } else if ((request.getParameter("sesso").charAt(0) != 'm') && (request.getParameter("sesso").charAt(0) != 'M')
            && (request.getParameter("sesso").charAt(0) != 'f')
            && (request.getParameter("sesso").charAt(0) != 'F')) {
        request.setAttribute("error3", true);
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("aggiungiPersona.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
    } else if (Pattern.matches("^[0-9]*$", request.getParameter("numTel")) == false) {
        request.setAttribute("error4", true);
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("aggiungiPersona.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
    } else if (!request.getParameter("email").contains("@")) {
        request.setAttribute("error5", true);
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("aggiungiPersona.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);

    } else {
        for (Persona persona : listaPersone) {

            if (Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id")) == persona.getId()) {

                found = true;

                request.setAttribute("error2", true);
                RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("aggiungiPersona.jsp");
                view.forward(request, response);

            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            try {
                PersonaQuery.aggiungiPersona(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id")),
                        request.getParameter("nome"), request.getParameter("cognome"),
                        Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("anni")), request.getParameter("sesso"),
                        request.getParameter("indirizzo"), request.getParameter("numTel"),
                        request.getParameter("email"));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            request.setAttribute("successo", true);
            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("aggiungiPersona.jsp");
            view.forward(request, response);
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Hi , you store that values in session and show in your form or i would suggest you do client side validation of data before submitting your form.. using `js` .

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

This very much depends on how your application is set up.
There are two basic approaches:

**UI validation**
If you UI is aware of which fields are mandatory then you can block the submit/post until all the required fields are filled correctly. This can reduce server traffic and help streamline the application.

**Server side validation**
How this is achieved is dependant on the set up, but if your set up is using a "post, redirect, get" approach then you will need to ensure that the data is mapped into the form ready for the next get.

Unfortunately with out knowing more about your codebase I can not offer much more help

Comment: now, i posted my code. I mean that it must be a method that allows me to keep the form filled in, because it must work even if, for example, all the fields are filled in and the email field does not have the @ symbol.